# how to get a tr id which is less than a number

Tags: jquery

I have following html table layout:

```
<table border="1" id="staff">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="12">
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="13">
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
 <tr id="15">
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="16">
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

for some reason, l want to find the tr id which will be lower than a number by jquery. Suppose, the number is 11, so the id less than 11 is 9,  again if the number is 7, then the id is 5. I am trying as follows:

```
var rank = 5;
var target_id = $('#staff tr').filter(function() {
    return this.id < rank;
}).last();

alert(target_id);
```

but it is not working. It is showing "object Object". how to get the tr id in this case.

Comment: How about just `$('#staff tr[id='+rank+']').prev().attr('id');`?

Comment: will it be able to find if the id of trs are not sequential, e,g tr ids are like in 5, 9, 2, 3, 10, 6 sequence?

Comment: No, this will look for the `previus` element that's in the same level as the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target_id` is a jQuery object, so you should assess its ID attribute to get its ID, i.e. `target_id.attr('id')`. Also, you should convert the ID into an integer to be safe, and to allow comparison, using `parseInt()`:

```
var rank = 5;
var target_id = $('#staff tr').filter(function() {
    return parseInt(this.id, 10) < rank;
}).last().attr('id');

alert(target_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
var rank = 5;
var target_id = $('#staff tr').filter(function() {
    return this.id < rank;
}).last().attr('id');

alert(target_id);
```

The original one just returns the (filtered) row